# Empty POST on Angular/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angular, authentication

I'm new to Angular 4. I've added a simple HTTP POST login & connected it to another, simple, PHP receiver which then connects to the DB to check if the credentials are correct.

Bad Code:

```
    login(username: string, password: string){
    var headers = new Headers();
    var creds ='http://localhost/crm/login/login.php';
    headers.append('content-type', 'application/X-www-form=urlencoded');
    return this._http.post(creds, {username: username, password: password}, {headers})
        .map((response: Response) => {
            let user = response.json();
            if(user && user.accid){
                this.isLoggedIn = true;
                this.loginType = user.accid; 

                sessionStorage.setItem('accid', JSON.stringify(user.accid));
                sessionStorage.setItem('status', JSON.stringify(user.status));
                sessionStorage.setItem('username', JSON.stringify(user.user));
                sessionStorage.setItem('uniqid', JSON.stringify(user.uniqid));
                return user;
            }else
                return false;

      });
}
```

The issue is, if I POST, the PHP server does not read any input at all, as if I POSTed nothing.

This is how I "fixed" it, but really this isn't a fix at all. This is basically using GET, except that I format the string itself. Obviously this is a horrible walkaround since now I have to accept GET requests on the PHP body, and the request itself is literally printed out in the browser's console on login.

```
login(username: string, password: string){
    var headers = new Headers();
    var creds ='http://localhost/crm/login/login.php?' + 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password;
    headers.append('content-type', 'application/X-www-form=urlencoded');
    return this._http.post(creds, '', {headers})
        .map((response: Response) => {
            let user = response.json();
            if(user && user.accid){
                this.isLoggedIn = true;
                this.loginType = user.accid; 

                sessionStorage.setItem('accid', JSON.stringify(user.accid));
                sessionStorage.setItem('status', JSON.stringify(user.status));
                sessionStorage.setItem('username', JSON.stringify(user.user));
                sessionStorage.setItem('uniqid', JSON.stringify(user.uniqid));
                return user;
            }else
                return false;

      });
}
```

PHP body

```
<?php
require_once '../config.php';

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

$parmSir = [];
if($_GET)
    foreach($_GET as $gettie)
        $parmSir[] = $gettie;

if($_POST)
    foreach($_POST as $postie)
        $parmSir[] = $postie;

$username = isset($parmSir[0]) ? $parmSir[0] : NULL;
$password = isset($parmSir[1]) ? $parmSir[1] : NULL;

$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);
$password = sha1($password, true);
$response = [];
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE password='$password' AND username='$username'");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($rows == 1){
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT account_type, employee_ID FROM user_accounts WHERE username ='$username'");
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
    $response['status'] = 'loggedin';
    $response['accid'] = $row['account_type'];
    $response['user'] = $username;
    $response['uniqid'] = $row['employee_ID'];
}
else
    $response['status'] = 'error';
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Not exactly sure why the PHP isn't recognizing POST/GET requests unless if I format the string in that specific manner. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to ensure the header's 'content-type' is 'application/json'. Otherwise, _POST and _GET will not read the content as required (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type).

Other posts have recommended to use $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA (now deprecated, replaced with php://input which I now use).

Here is how it now looks like:

```
    login(username: string, password: string){
    var headers = new Headers();
    var creds ='http://localhost/crm/login/login.php';
    headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
    return this._http.post(creds, {username: username, password: password}, {headers})
        .map((response: Response) => {
            let user = response.json();
            if(user && user.accid){
                this.isLoggedIn = true;
                this.loginType = user.accid; 
                
                sessionStorage.setItem('accid', JSON.stringify(user.accid));
                sessionStorage.setItem('status', JSON.stringify(user.status));
                sessionStorage.setItem('username', JSON.stringify(user.user));
                sessionStorage.setItem('uniqid', JSON.stringify(user.uniqid));
                return user;
            }else if(user.status == "error"){
                return false;
            }else
                return false;

      });
}
```

And the .PHP:

```
<?php
require_once '../config.php';
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

if(strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'POST') != 0){
    throw new Exception('Request method must be POST!');
}

$input = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')),true);

$username = $input['username'];
$password = $input['password'];

$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);
$password = sha1($password, true);
$response = [];
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE password='$password' AND username='$username'");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($rows == 1){
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT account_type, employee_ID FROM user_accounts WHERE username ='$username'");
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
    $response['status'] = 'loggedin';
    $response['accid'] = $row['account_type'];
    $response['user'] = $username;
    $response['uniqid'] = $row['employee_ID'];
}
else
    $response['status'] = 'error';
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```